# MUnit test fails with Maven (Failed to invoke lifecycle phase "start")

Tags: maven, mule, munit

We have a Mule flow with an associated MUnit test suite. The test runs fine when executed out of Anypoint Studio (right-click in the MUnit flow and select "Run MUnit Suite").

However with Maven with `mvn test -X` from the command line we get exceptions.

We are using Anypoint Studio 5.4.1 MUnit 1.1.0 Mule Version 3.6.1

Full stack trace:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.mulesoft.munit.tools:munit-maven-plugin:1.1.0:test (test) on project integration_sci_entityapi: Execution test of goal com.mulesoft.munit.tools:munit-maven-plugin:1.1.0:test failed: org.mule.api.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Failed to invoke lifecycle phase "start" on object: org.mule.util.queue.DelegateQueueManager@494a48cc: org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.deleteQuietly(Ljava/io/File;)Z -> [Help 1]
 org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal com.mulesoft.munit.tools:munit-maven-plugin:1.1.0:test (test) on project integration_sci_entityapi: Execution test of goal com.mulesoft.munit.tools:munit-maven-plugin:1.1.0:test failed: org.mule.api.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Failed to invoke lifecycle phase "start" on object: org.mule.util.queue.DelegateQueueManager@494a48cc
         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:224)
         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
         at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
         at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
         at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
         at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:862)
         at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:286)
         at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:197)
         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
         at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
         at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
         at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
         at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
 Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution test of goal com.mulesoft.munit.tools:munit-maven-plugin:1.1.0:test failed: org.mule.api.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Failed to invoke lifecycle phase "start" on object: org.mule.util.queue.DelegateQueueManager@494a48cc
         at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:145)
         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
         ... 20 more
 Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.mule.api.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Failed to invoke lifecycle phase "start" on object: org.mule.util.queue.DelegateQueueManager@494a48cc
         at org.mule.munit.runner.mule.MunitSuiteRunner.<init>(MunitSuiteRunner.java:48)
         at org.mule.MUnitMojo.buildRunnerFor(MUnitMojo.java:311)
         at org.mule.MUnitMojo.doExecute(MUnitMojo.java:173)
         at org.mule.MUnitMojo.execute(MUnitMojo.java:122)
         at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
         ... 21 more
 Caused by: org.mule.api.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Failed to invoke lifecycle phase "start" on object: org.mule.util.queue.DelegateQueueManager@494a48cc
         at org.mule.lifecycle.phases.DefaultLifecyclePhase.applyLifecycle(DefaultLifecyclePhase.java:248)
         at org.mule.lifecycle.RegistryLifecycleManager$RegistryLifecycleCallback.onTransition(RegistryLifecycleManager.java:273)
         at org.mule.lifecycle.RegistryLifecycleManager.invokePhase(RegistryLifecycleManager.java:152)
         at org.mule.lifecycle.RegistryLifecycleManager.fireLifecycle(RegistryLifecycleManager.java:123)
         at org.mule.registry.AbstractRegistryBroker.fireLifecycle(AbstractRegistryBroker.java:76)
         at org.mule.registry.MuleRegistryHelper.fireLifecycle(MuleRegistryHelper.java:136)
         at org.mule.lifecycle.MuleContextLifecycleManager$MuleContextLifecycleCallback.onTransition(MuleContextLifecycleManager.java:91)
         at org.mule.lifecycle.MuleContextLifecycleManager$MuleContextLifecycleCallback.onTransition(MuleContextLifecycleManager.java:87)
         at org.mule.lifecycle.MuleContextLifecycleManager.invokePhase(MuleContextLifecycleManager.java:69)
         at org.mule.lifecycle.MuleContextLifecycleManager.fireLifecycle(MuleContextLifecycleManager.java:61)
         at org.mule.DefaultMuleContext.start(DefaultMuleContext.java:278)
         at org.mule.munit.runner.MuleContextManager.startMule(MuleContextManager.java:62)
         at org.mule.munit.runner.MuleContextManager.startMule(MuleContextManager.java:57)
         at org.mule.munit.runner.mule.MunitSuiteRunner.<init>(MunitSuiteRunner.java:42)
         ... 25 more
 Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.deleteQuietly(Ljava/io/File;)Z
         at org.mule.util.journal.TransactionJournalFile.clear(TransactionJournalFile.java:161)
         at org.mule.util.journal.TransactionJournal.clear(TransactionJournal.java:135)
         at org.mule.util.journal.queue.AbstractQueueTransactionJournal.clear(AbstractQueueTransactionJournal.java:121)
         at org.mule.util.journal.queue.LocalTxQueueTransactionRecoverer.recover(LocalTxQueueTransactionRecoverer.java:122)
         at org.mule.util.queue.TransactionalQueueManager.start(TransactionalQueueManager.java:91)
         at org.mule.util.queue.DelegateQueueManager.start(DelegateQueueManager.java:69)
         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
         at org.mule.lifecycle.phases.DefaultLifecyclePhase.applyLifecycle(DefaultLifecyclePhase.java:237)
         ... 38 more
```

And here is the POM file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>za.co.company.cmpy</groupId>
<artifactId>integration_cmpy_entityapi</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>mule</packaging>

<name>${project.groupId} :: ${project.artifactId} :: ${project.packaging}</name>

<scm>
    <connection>scm:git:http://git.company.co.za/scm/cmpyon/Integration_cmpy_EntityApi.git</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:git:http://git.company.co.za/scm/cmpyon/Integration_cmpy_EntityApi.git</developerConnection>
    <url>http://git.company.co.za/projects/cmpyON/repos/Integration_cmpy_EntityApi.git/browse</url>
</scm>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

    <mule.version>3.6.2</mule.version>
    <eclipsePluginVersion>2.8</eclipsePluginVersion>
    <jdkName>JavaSE-1.7</jdkName>
    <jdk.version>1.7</jdk.version>
    <junit.version>4.9</junit.version>



<munit.version>1.1.0</munit.version>
<mule.munit.support.version>3.6.1</mule.munit.support.version>
</properties>

<build>
    <filters>
        <filter>src/main/resources/integration-cmpy-entityapi.properties</filter>
    </filters>

    <resources>
        <resource>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <!-- Use a newer version of the install plugin than what your Maven uses 
        by default. The older version failed to install the project if there was 
        no target/classes folder. Since we use mule packaging on the project we actually 
        create and attach the zip that must be installed. -->
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings 
                only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself. -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                        <pluginExecutions>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>org.mule.tools</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>maven-mule-plugin</artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>[1.6,)</versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>attach-test-resources</goal>
                                        <goal>filter-resources      </goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <ignore/>
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>
                        </pluginExecutions>
                    </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <plugins>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.mule.tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-mule-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.9</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <copyToAppsDirectory>true</copyToAppsDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                <target>${jdk.version}</target>
                <encoding>ISO-8859-1</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>project</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${eclipsePluginVersion}</version>
            <configuration>
                <!-- by default download all sources when generating project files -->
                <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>add-resource</id>
                    <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>add-resource</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>src/main/app/</directory>
                    </resource>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>src/main/api/</directory>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>java</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>org.mule.MuleServer</mainClass>
                <arguments>
                    <argument>-config</argument>
                    <argument>src/main/app/mule-config.xml</argument>
                </arguments>
                <classpathScope>compile</classpathScope>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <!--Install clover-plugins -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-clover-plugins</id>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <overWriteReleases>true</overWriteReleases>
                        <overWriteSnapshots>true</overWriteSnapshots>
                        <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                        <stripVersion>true</stripVersion>

                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.testOutputDirectory}</outputDirectory>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>com.cloveretl</groupId>
                                <artifactId>cloveretl-engine</artifactId>
                                <version>${mule.version}</version>
                                <type>zip</type>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <tasks>
                            <!-- Using an ant task to deflate cloveretl-engine.zip -->
                            <unzip dest="${project.build.testOutputDirectory}" src="${project.build.testOutputDirectory}/cloveretl-engine.zip"/>
                        </tasks>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.github.nicholasastuart</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-mmc-rest-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>mule-deploy</id>
                    <phase>install</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>deploy</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <name>${artifactId}</name>
                        <username>${mulemmc.username}</username>
                        <password>${mulemmc.password}</password>
                        <version>${version}</version>
                        <serverGroup>${mulemmc.serverGroup}</serverGroup>
                        <muleApiUrl>${mulemmc.muleApiUrl}</muleApiUrl>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    <plugin>
            <groupId>com.mulesoft.munit.tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>munit-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${munit.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>test</id>
                    <phase>test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <coverage>
                    <runCoverage>true</runCoverage>
                    <formats>
                        <format>html</format>
                    </formats>
                </coverage>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
<testResources>
        <testResource>
            <directory>src/test/munit</directory>
        </testResource>
    <testResource>
            <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
        </testResource>
    </testResources>
</build>

<!-- plugins for creating site reports -->
<reporting>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.2</version>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <configuration>
                <configLocation>http://mulesoft.org/download/attachments/92/checkstyle.xml?version=1</configLocation>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <configuration>
                <targetJdk>${jdk.version}</targetJdk>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>taglist-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <tags>
                    <tag>TODO</tag>
                    <tag>@todo</tag>
                    <tag>FIXME</tag>
                    <tag>@fixme</tag>
                    <tag>@deprecated</tag>
                </tags>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jxr-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                <links>
                    <link>http://java.sun.com/j2ee/1.4/docs/api</link>
                    <link>http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api</link>
                    <link>http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api</link>
                </links>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jdepend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0-beta-2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</reporting>

<!-- Mule Dependencies -->
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>za.co.cmpy.core.shared</groupId>
        <artifactId>MessageSpec</artifactId>
        <version>1.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-core</artifactId>
        <version>${mule.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mulesoft.muleesb.modules</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-module-boot-ee</artifactId>
        <version>${mule.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Xml configuration -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-module-spring-config</artifactId>
        <version>${mule.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mulesoft.muleesb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-core-ee</artifactId>
        <version>${mule.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mulesoft.muleesb.modules</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-module-data-mapper</artifactId>
        <version>${mule.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Xml configuration -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mulesoft.muleesb.modules</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-module-spring-config-ee</artifactId>
        <version>${mule.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Mule Transports -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.transports</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-transport-file</artifactId>
        <version>${mule.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.transports</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-transport-http</artifactId>
        <version>${mule.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.transports</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-transport-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${mule.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.transports</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-transport-jms</artifactId>
        <version>${mule.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.transports</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-transport-vm</artifactId>
        <version>${mule.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>


    <!-- Mule Modules -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-module-client</artifactId>
        <version>${mule.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-module-cxf</artifactId>
        <version>${mule.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-module-management</artifactId>
        <version>${mule.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-module-scripting</artifactId>
        <version>${mule.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-module-sxc</artifactId>
        <version>${mule.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-module-xml</artifactId>
        <version>${mule.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- for testing -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.tests</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-tests-functional</artifactId>
        <version>${mule.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mockobjects</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockobjects-core</artifactId>
        <version>0.09</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.cloveretl</groupId>
        <artifactId>cloveretl-engine</artifactId>
        <version>${mule.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mulesoft.muleesb.transports</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-transport-ftp-ee</artifactId>
        <version>${mule.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.transports</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-transport-sftp</artifactId>
        <version>${mule.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-module-db</artifactId>
        <version>${mule.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
        <artifactId>sqljdbc4</artifactId>
        <version>4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.beanio</groupId>
        <artifactId>beanio</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-module-json</artifactId>
        <version>${mule.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ricston.connectors</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-mybatis-connector</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
        <artifactId>mybatis</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.jtds</groupId>
        <artifactId>jtds</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.transports</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-transport-quartz</artifactId>
        <version>${mule.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-module-http</artifactId>
        <version>${mule.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jcraft</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsch</artifactId>
        <version>0.1.42</version>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.mulesoft.muleesb.modules</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-module-batch-ee</artifactId>
        <version>${mule.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.mulesoft.munit</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-munit-support</artifactId>
        <version>${mule.munit.support.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.mulesoft.munit</groupId>
        <artifactId>munit-runner</artifactId>
        <version>${munit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>


<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>deployment</id>
        <name>Internal Releases</name>
        <url>${nexus.release}</url>
    </repository>
    <snapshotRepository>
        <id>deploymentSnapshot</id>
        <name>Internal Releases</name>
        <url>${nexus.snapshot}</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
</distributionManagement>
```

Comment: Can you post your pom ? Most of the time this are dependecy issues (missing or wrong version pick)

Comment: Thanks @MauroRocco I have posted the POM in full.

Comment: Try to put mule.munit.support.version equal to 3.6.0, this is what docs says for 3.6.x.

Comment: OK, making some progress. The `mule.munit.support.version` change causes other Log4J issues. Another suggestion was to check the `commons-ui` version which I have updated and now the tests are running, but I'm getting property replacement problems due to our common property file (the other post you commented on).

Comment: We've got a property file flow that just loads the property files for the project, but for some reason when running the tests the property replacements doesn't happen in this file:
`<spring:beans>
  <context:property-placeholder
   location="${property.file.locations}" />
</spring:beans>`

Comment: Hi, this is starting to look like a chat or personal consultancy, if you have another problem post another question and please add always details. One hint, if this property.file.locations is defined in another property file in a mule flow this will not work property file are loaded all togheter.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please update the mule.munit.support.version to 3.6.2? That is the latest released version. I saw this kind of errors in the past and I solved it by doing that. In case that it continues failing, could you attach an example of the flow that you are testing?

Answer (score 0):

Update the munit version to latest one. I had the same error while executing the munit.

```
     <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mulesoft.munit</groupId>
        <artifactId>munit-runner</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
        <classifier>mule-plugin</classifier>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mulesoft.munit</groupId>
        <artifactId>munit-tools</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
        <classifier>mule-plugin</classifier>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```